# Using TfidfVectorizer on a Dictionary of Lists

Tags: python, dictionary, machine-learning, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I have a large corpus stored as a dict of 25 lists that I'd like to analyze with SKLearn's `TfidfVectorizer`.  Each list contains many strings.  Now, I care both about the overall term frequency (tf) throughout the whole corpus and the most unique terms within each list of the 25 strings (idf). The problem is, I haven't found a way to pass this kind of object to the TfidfVectorizer.  Passing the dict just vectorizes the keys, passing the values yields an `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'` (I guess it expects a string.)

Thanks in advance.

Update: Now including my preprocessing step, which used a `dict` of area, ID pairs called `buckets`

```
for area in buckets:
    area_docs = []
    for value in buckets[area]:   
        if 'filename_%s.txt' % value in os.listdir(directory):
            fin = open(directory+'/filename_%s.txt' % value, 'r').read() 
            area_docs.append(fin)
            buckets[area] = area_docs



corpus = buckets.values()
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, stop_words='english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
idf = vectorizer.idf_
d = dict(zip(vectorizer.get_feature_names(), idf))
sorted_d = sorted(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
sorted_d[:50]
```

Comment: `TfidfVectorizer` is used to "Convert a collection of raw documents to a matrix of TF-IDF features." It wants a sequence of documents. Your dictionary seems to be processed somehow, so it isn't clear what you expect `TfidfVectorizer` to do.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga. Edited to reflect that list items are multi-word strings (in my actual case documents ~2000 words).  The lists are basically subcorpora.  In effect, I want to know the most distinctive words in a given subcorpus (list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TfidfVectorizer` wants a list of strings, where each string is a document. Your `area_docs` variable is already a list of strings, so when you call `buckets.values()` you get a list of lists of strings, which is too many dimensions for TfidfVectorizer. You need to flatten that list. Code below is in Python3, with just one line changed and another new line added:

```
for area in buckets:
    area_docs = []
    for value in buckets[area]:   
        if 'filename_%s.txt' % value in os.listdir(directory):
            fin = open(directory+'/filename_%s.txt' % value, 'r').read() 
            area_docs.append(fin)
            buckets[area] = area_docs

corpus = list(buckets.values()) # Get your list of lists of strings
corpus = sum(corpus, []) # Good trick for flattening 2D lists to 1D
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, stop_words='english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
idf = vectorizer.idf_
d = dict(zip(vectorizer.get_feature_names(), idf))
sorted_d = sorted(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
sorted_d[:50]
```

That should do it!